# Raspberry Pi long button hold vs short click to control LEDs

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

First, a disclaimer, I am absolutely new to Raspberry Pi and Python so I might have done some total nonsense here, my apologies.

As a first exercise I tried making a binary counter which would light up to 4 LEDs one by one by pressing a physical GPIO button, which would increment them by one each time, I've succeeded in doing that, and I wanted to add more functionality where if I press and hold the button for longer (2 seconds in this case), the counter will reset to 0 and all LEDs will go off, for example.

Here is the code of what I've done by now, but the behaviour is not exactly what I intended...

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep, time

led0 = 40
led1 = 35
led2 = 33
led3 = 31
btn = 7

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setup(led0,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(led1,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(led2,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(led3,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(btn,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

start_time = 0
counter = 0
time_counter = 0

time_flag = False
button_flag = True


try:
    while True:
        if GPIO.input(btn) == 0: # Button is pressed
            if time_flag == True:
                time_counter = time() - start_time
                #print (f"time_counter = {round(time_counter,2)}s")            
                
            if button_flag == True:
                time_flag = True
                start_time = time()

                counter += 1
                #print (time_counter)
                
                if time_counter > 2:
                    counter = 0
                if counter == 16:
                    counter = 0
                    
                print (format(counter, '02d'), format(counter, '04b')) # bin(counter)[2:].zfill(4)
                button_flag = False
                sleep(0.05)
                
                GPIO.output(led0, counter & 0x01)
                GPIO.output(led1, counter & 0x02)
                GPIO.output(led2, counter & 0x04)
                GPIO.output(led3, counter & 0x08)
        else:
            button_flag = True
            time_counter = 0


except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

The problem is I want the particular code to be executed when I keep holding the button for long, but what happens in turn, is that if I hold the button for long, nothing happens at first, and I need to press it once again for it to do what I want and reset the counter to turn off all the LEDs.

Here is a GIF which demonstrates the issue, in the first part I just increment using fast clicks, and later I hold the button for long (2 sec), but it doesn't work as intended, and I have to click once again for it to take effect.

[**Raspberry LED Issue GIF**](https://i.ibb.co/VpHG8kg/raspberry-led-question.gif)

Would be grateful for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move your time check inside the time_flag check block. And also if time_counter reaches its limits, reflect changes to the leds immediately after timeout occurs

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep, time

led0 = 40
led1 = 35
led2 = 33
led3 = 31
btn = 7

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setup(led0,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(led1,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(led2,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(led3,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(btn,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

start_time = 0
counter = 0
time_counter = 0

time_flag = False
button_flag = True


try:
    while True:
    if GPIO.input(btn) == 0: # Button is pressed
        if time_flag == True:
            time_counter = time() - start_time
            #print (f"time_counter = {round(time_counter,2)}s")            
            
            if time_counter > 2:
                counter = 0
                GPIO.output(led0, counter & 0x01)
                GPIO.output(led1, counter & 0x02)
                GPIO.output(led2, counter & 0x04)
                GPIO.output(led3, counter & 0x08)


        if button_flag == True:
            time_flag = True
            start_time = time()

            counter += 1
            #print (time_counter)
            
            if counter == 16:
                counter = 0
                
            print (format(counter, '02d'), format(counter, '04b')) # bin(counter)[2:].zfill(4)
            button_flag = False
            sleep(0.05)
            
            GPIO.output(led0, counter & 0x01)
            GPIO.output(led1, counter & 0x02)
            GPIO.output(led2, counter & 0x04)
            GPIO.output(led3, counter & 0x08)
    else:
        button_flag = True
        time_counter = 0


except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is when you hold the button, `button_flag` will set to `False` after 1 loop. Then the code under `if button_flag == True` block will no longer run when button is still pressed. Once button is released, the `else` block will run and set `time_counter` to 0. Then the your `if time_counter > 2` condition is never met and thus never set `counter` to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code can help

```
#/usr/bin/python3

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep, time
btn = 8

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(btn,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
while True:
    if(GPIO.input(btn) == 1): #check button pressed
        start = time() #start timer
        sleep(0.02)
        while(GPIO.input(btn) == 1): #always loop if button pressed
            sleep(0.01)
        length = time() - start #get long time button pressed
        long_press_length = 2 # seconds
        if (length > long_press_length): #if button greater 2 second statement active
            # long press function
        else:
            # short press function
        print("press duration: "+str(length))
    else:
        print("await")
    sleep(1)
```

this code works :

1. get status button pressed or not
2. check again with while
3. if button not pressed while will stop
4. the timer detect second  button pressed
5. if more 2 second will be detected

Comment: When posting code, provide what language you are using (this looks like Python), and an explanation of the code.